# call the ok button of a dialog

Tags: android, dialog, action

i have a custom dialog having an **EditText** a **button ("default")** and the **ok/cancel buttons**
i perfectly programmed the dialog so the user enters a value to the EditText and either chooses the ok to accept or cancel to cancel the dialog

my problem is that i want to program the **default button** to call the ok button...
i also want to know how to just close the dialog (also from the default button)

here is my code

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompt, null);
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.edtitext);
Button defaultButton = (Button) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.button);
defaultButton.setOnClickListener(new setOnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean setOnClickListener()
    {
        //default
        //how to call the ok button actions
        //how to just close the dialog
        return false;
    }
};
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
    {
        //ok actions
    }
}).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
    {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});

AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: just simply call the dialog.dismiss() function on your button click so the dialog was canceled easily

Comment: what do you mean by the dialog variable ??

Comment: simply like you show the dialog with the alertDialog.show for showing the dialog simply call the alertDialog.dismiss() for canceling the dialog

Comment: ok then how can i call the ok button action

Answer (score 0):

You have already set the listener for the negative button, it's the same for positive button :

```
.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

    }
});
```

And if you wanna close the dialog, just call :

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: again..i want to program the default button to call the ok button... im already done with the ok as u can see in the above code